# Tablelayout - sort rows on column header click

Tags: android, sorting, tablelayout

I've created a `TableLayout` and added rows to it dynamically. I want to sort table content on column header click. Just as in HTML, we can easily sort data using datatables. Can I implement the same functionality in **Android** `TableLayout` using some jar files or existing Android functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, you can use [`Collection.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) for it.

There are so many tutorials on it. see [arraylist-example-using-collections-sort](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/sort-arraylist-example-using-collections-sort/). this is logic for sorting.
you can make a method that you can execute on your table header click.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply praveen Sharma!! I will try this out and get back to u in case if have a doubt...