# Sort TableLayout on header column click

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout (header + rows added dynamically at runtime) :

Header 1 Header 2 Header 3
  A1       B1       C1
  A2       B2       C2
...

I want to implement a logic that sorts this table based on column header click.

Is there a way to do this straight forward  in Android without making action listners on header textViews and arrange the rows added dynamically ?

Thank you.

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063667/tablelayout-sort-rows-on-column-header-click)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to make sure first before moving to a classic java manipulations, if there is anything supported in Android that handle this.